Relationship between decay rate and stationary state for the Lindblad Equation
I would like to know what is the role of the decay rate $gamma$ in the Lindblad equation written in the diagonal form
\begin{equation}
\dot{\rho}(t)= i[H,\rho(t)]+\gamma\sum_{\alpha}L_{\alpha}\rho(t)L^\dagger_{\alpha}-\frac{1}{2}\{L^\dagger_{\alpha}L_{\alpha},\rho(t)\}
\end{equation}
and - in particular - if the stationary state of the process can be influenced by its value, i.e., if the strength of the coupling between the system and the environment can influence the stationary state the system will eventually reach.

There are cases where $\gamma$ has no influence on the stationary state: for example if the Hamiltonian and the dissipative part leave the same state invariant individually, then this is of course true for their sum, regardless of the value of $\gamma$. One scenario where this comes up is when all $L_\alpha$ are Hermitian because then both $-i[H,\cdot]$ and the dissipative part leave the maximally mixed state invariant separately so $\gamma$ does not play a role in that regard.
However, if the kernels of these individual terms do need share any non-zero elements then the value of $\gamma$ does indeed have an effect.  A simple example which showcases this behaviour is $H=\sigma_x$ and $L_\alpha=|0\rangle\langle 1|$. Then from the representation matrix (cf. here and here)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -i & i & \gamma \\
 -i & -\frac{\gamma}{2} & 0 & i \\
 i & 0 & -\frac{\gamma}{2} & -i \\
 0 & i & -i & -\gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
of the Lindbladian one readily verifies that ${\rm ker}(L)$ for all $\gamma\geq 0$ is spanned by the state
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1-\frac{4}{\gamma^2+8} & \frac{2 i \gamma}{\gamma^2+8} \\
 -\frac{2 i \gamma}{\gamma^2+8} & \frac{4}{\gamma^2+8} 
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
This for small coupling strengths $\gamma$ restores the maximally mixed state (which is always stationary with respect to $-i[H,\cdot]$) while for large $\gamma$ the stationary state becomes the ground state $|0\rangle\langle 0|$.
